# getting a specific format from GetDateTimeFormats()

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, datetime-format, date-formatting

I need to know how to access a specific datetime format. I found this [GetDateTimeFormats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and I know C# can generate the formats I need, since I can see them both on the documentation page, and in Visual Studio's "Locals" tab (at runtime, next to Watch)

However, it doesn't really give any hints as to what any of the formats are called or how to access a specific one. It's just a huge list of all the formats it can do?

I don't really want this question to be about a specific format though, so much as how to use this method to find how to access it, or at least what it's called. But, specifics help, so, one of the formats I'm looking for is YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ (I...THINK I did the capitalization right...)

I would just take note of the index in the result set and use that, despite probably being pretty resource intensive, but I saw in the remarks section that the method's output can vary depending on the culture settings and/or input.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Its a huge list of formats that NET *uses* for various things like `DateTime.Try / Parse`

Comment: What Do you mean by "what any of the formats are called or how to access a specific one. It's just a huge list of all the formats it can do?"?
Do you seek to find a name for every one of them or you just confused about their purpose and usage as in @Plutonix stated one good example?

Comment: @daniel that's precisely what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: @Ali seeking a name for them was just an means to an end. I found functions like ToLongTimeString() and ToShortDateString(), outputting hh:mm:ss AM/PM and MM/DD/YYYY, respectively. I thought, if someone didn't know where to point me, but knew what the format was "called" that would at least help me search.

Comment: @donutguy640? what do you mean by Z in "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ"? Does it refer to millisecond?
Some of them may have names and some may not. but if you're searching for a specific format the documentation listed below is a good start: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: As I understand it, Z just means UTC, per [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?csw=1#timestamp)